# <error-page> is not working for servlet

Tags: java, apache, jsp, servlets, web.xml

when exception in servlet then  is not working but for jsp its work properly

web.xml code

```
<error-page>
<exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
<location>/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

servlet code

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)throws ServletException, IOException 
{
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        try {
            /*
             * TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code.
             */
          String a=null;
          a.toString();//this line will throw exception
        } 
finally {            
            out.close();
        }
}
```

it does not redirect to error.jsp

Comment: I'm going to guess there is a particular error in your server logs: "response already committed". Please check the log file.

Comment: @Gimby , There is no exception in server log. I am not able to understand why it is not getting executed. please suggest

Comment: Try moving the exception throwing code to the very top of the code (above the `response.getWriter()`) to see if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Servlet code
this will throw the exception to the general error page

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException {
           // response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            try {
                /*
                 * TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code.
                 */
               String a=null;
               a.toString();

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                throw new ServletException(e);
            }

            finally {            
                //dont write out.close();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

when we write catch block in servlet it does not work and when we does not write catch block its work properly.
Servlet Code

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException{
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        DAL db=null;
        ResultSet rs=null;
           parameter p1=new parameter();

          // Object param[];
          // List<Object> param=new ArrayList<Object>();
           long myId=0;
        try {


           db=new DAL();
           String name=request.getParameter("fn");
           db.setQuery("{call usp_StudentInsertData(?,?)}"); 
           db.setInParam(1,name);
           db.setInParam(2,1000);
           db.insertUpdate();
           out.println("insert");
           response.sendRedirect("home.jsp");
           } 
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }
        finally {            
           }
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain a little more here?